# Immediate object initialization confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a js file that makes use of JScroll. The callback for the `jsp-scroll-y` event is defined in the following function

```
 function initWall() {
     //callback from jqueryscrollpane
     Scroll_TimeLine_Instance = function (event, scrollPositionY, isAtTop, isAtBottom){     
         //get more content
         if (isAtBottom) {
             GetMoreDate(objid, vwrsid, secid, orgid, incflwr, qty, mintlid, maxtlid, successGetTimeLineCallback, failureGetTimeLineCallback);
         }
     }();
}
```

Another function is defined that then binds this callback to the jsScroll

```
function reapplyScroll() {
     Utilities.DestroyScrollBar($(_target).closest('.widgetBody'));
     Utilities.ApplyScrollBar($(_target).closest('.widgetBody'), false, Scroll_TimeLine_Instance);
            }

Utilities.ApplyScrollBar = function (element, showScrollBar, scrollCallback) {
    $(element).jScrollPane({
        horizontalGutter: 5,
        verticalGutter: 5,
        'showArrows': false
    }).bind('jsp-scroll-y', scrollCallback);

    if (!showScrollBar) {
        $(element).find('.jspDrag').hide();
    }
}
```

The callback was never called, and I found this was because it was undefined. If I remove the `Immediate object initialization` (); from after the creation of the function everything works fine.

Can anyone explain this? I don't understand why it was being called immediate anyway, so i assume this is an error on the part of whoever created it, and I have no idea why it would cause this variable to be undefined?

Answer (score 0):

It is `undefined` because the function (*that is immediately called*) does not `return` any value

So it seems indeed that this is a *bug* of the library..

---

Either remove the `();` at the end, or if you want to call it right there as well just invoke it in the following line

```
function initWall() {
     //callback from jqueryscrollpane
     Scroll_TimeLine_Instance = function (event, scrollPositionY, isAtTop, isAtBottom){     
         //get more content
         if (isAtBottom) {
             GetMoreDate(objid, vwrsid, secid, orgid, incflwr, qty, mintlid, maxtlid, successGetTimeLineCallback, failureGetTimeLineCallback);
         }
     }; /// this is assigning the function to our variable
     Scroll_TimeLine_Instance (); // this is the invokation
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little please? Im unsure why not returning a value would cause the  would cause it to be undefined.

Comment: @DavidB the `varname = someexpression` means that `varname` will be assigned the result of the `someexpression`. If someexpression is a function definition, that definition will be assigned. but if you invoke that function right there with the `();` the result of that function call will be what gets assigned to `varname`. Since the function does not have a `return` statement and thus does not return a value, it is undefined what to assign, and that is what ultimately gets assigned (*an `undefined` value*)

Comment: Thanks guys that explains it. Ive already solved the issue just wasn't sure why it was happening. Gaby if you'd like to add this as an answer Ill accept